# Homebrew formual testing

Tags: ruby, macos, package, erlang, homebrew

I am writing a formula installer with dependecies:

```rb
depends_on "yaws" => "2.0.9"
depends_on "erlang"
depends_on "gcc" => "4.9.1"
depends_on "graphviz" => "2.47.1"
```

Now I am in the phase of testing, and  it cannot start, as I get this error message:

```
Error: referl is missing test dependencies: erlang
```

(referl is te formula name)

Even for this little trivially bad test case:

```rb
test do
   assert_true(false)
end
```

I am using this command for running test cases manually:

```
brew test referl.rb
```

What is problem there? Why it cannot find erlang for testing?

Thanks for any help!